# Select dropdown items is not showing

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, input

I need some help with my code. I have got a problem with select the item in the select options. I am using dropkick select options and when I try to click on the down arrow button of the select options, it will not dropdown the item. There is something wrong with the code.

When I try this:

```
<form class="list-dropdown" action="" method="post" name="listSelect">

    <input type="hidden" name="data[landing_page]" value="/broadcasts">
    <div class="dk-select " id="dk0-datalistactivate"><div class="dk-selected " tabindex="0" id="dk0-combobox" aria-live="assertive" aria-owns="dk0-listbox" role="combobox">dubc_traffic</div><ul class="dk-select-options" id="dk0-listbox" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false"><li class="dk-option  dk-option-selected" data-value="" text="dubc_traffic" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="dk0-listSelectionActiveOption">dubc_traffic</li></ul></div><select name="data[List][activate]" id="datalistactivate" data-dkcacheid="0">

<option selected="selected" id="listSelectionActiveOption" value="">dubc_traffic</option>

<option selected="selected" id="listSelectionActiveOption" value="">dubc_traffic 2</option>
loading lists …

    </select>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

It will not work, but when I try this it will work:

```
<select class="dk-select select-options select-options" id="dk0-datalistactivate">
    <option>dubc_traffic ass</option>
</select>
```

Here is the code:

```
<style type="text/css">

.lists-dropdown {
    color: #343434;
    float: left;
    display: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 12px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.lists-dropdown label {
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.lists-dropdown form {
    left: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}



.topnav .dk-select, .topnav .dk-select-options {
    width: 180px;
}

.dk-select, .dk-select-multi {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dk-select, .dk-select *, .dk-select *:before, .dk-select *:after, .dk-select-multi, .dk-select-multi *, .dk-select-multi *:before, .dk-select-multi *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.topnav .dk-selected {
    height: auto;
}
.dk-selected {
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ababab;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 2em 0 .5em;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.dk-select, .dk-select *, .dk-select *:before, .dk-select *:after, .dk-select-multi, .dk-select-multi *, .dk-select-multi *:before, .dk-select-multi *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dk-selected:before {
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: .25em .25em 0;
    border-top-color: #ababab;
    margin: -0.125em .5em 0 0;
}

.dk-selected:before, .dk-selected:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.dk-selected:after {
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ababab;
    margin: 0 1.5em 0 0;
}

.dk-selected:before, .dk-selected:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.dk-select .dk-select-options {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
}
.topnav .dk-select, .topnav .dk-select-options {
    width: 180px;
}
.dk-select-options {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ababab;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: 18.5em;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.dk-option {
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.dk-option-selected {
    background-color: #00adef;
    color: #fff;
}

select[data-dkcacheid] {
    display: none;
}

.lists-dropdown select {
    font-size: 16px;
}
form .searchinputbox, form .searchbox, form select {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dbdcde;
    color: #505e67;
    height: 30px;
}

form .searchinputbox option, form .searchbox option, form select option {
    color: #505e67;
}

user agent stylesheet
option {
    font-weight: normal;
    display: block;
    white-space: pre;
    min-height: 1.2em;
    padding: 0px 2px 1px;
}
</style>

<form class="list-dropdown" action="" method="post" name="listSelect">

    <input type="hidden" name="data[landing_page]" value="/broadcasts">
    <div class="dk-select " id="dk0-datalistactivate"><div class="dk-selected " tabindex="0" id="dk0-combobox" aria-live="assertive" aria-owns="dk0-listbox" role="combobox">dubc_traffic</div><ul class="dk-select-options" id="dk0-listbox" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false"><li class="dk-option  dk-option-selected" data-value="" text="dubc_traffic" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="dk0-listSelectionActiveOption">dubc_traffic</li></ul></div><select name="data[List][activate]" id="datalistactivate" data-dkcacheid="0">

<option selected="selected" id="listSelectionActiveOption" value="">dubc_traffic</option>

<option selected="selected" id="listSelectionActiveOption" value="">dubc_traffic 2</option>
loading lists …

    </select>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="sess_token" value="388289602566325fdeb6bce2a708c6d46ca2ac1c">
</form>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rynawLx2/

I understand that I did not add more than one item, but it will not dropdown the items when I click on it. I want to use the second select options below the first one in that link on above because I like the skin that come with the line next to the down arrow.

Can you please help me how to get the select options to work with dropdown items when I click on the items or on the down arrows?

I want to add more than one item using that select options.

Thank you.

Comment: ID's are meant to be unique. Both `<option>`'s bear the same ID. Use a class instead.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thank you for your advice, what class I should use instead and what do I need to replace it with `<option>` to get the items to dropdown?

Comment: Welcome. Well Robert, in that area I can't help you much from memory. TBH, I don't do much front-end stuff anymore, mostly backend. *But*, I am good at Googling and finding code that I feel would work. Give me a minute and I'll (try and) find something for you. You'll most likely need JS for this also. I was good back then though *lol!*

Comment: Ok, here's one you can try https://stackoverflow.com/q/45769480/1415724 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/44712226/1415724 --- Keep on Googling with these keywords I used "dropdown select show in second dropdown javascript", hope it helps.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thank you for the links, but unforunately both links dont show exactly what I have found. I know its easy to get the select options dropdown items to work by using `<select>
    <option>dubc_traffic</option>
    <option>dubc_traffic 2</option>
</select>` but I dont know how I can use that second select options in that jsfiddle link to make it to work. Can you help?

Comment: Welcome. Sorry, this is JS stuff and that and I don't make very good bedfellows. I added the "javascript" tag to the question, so hopefully someone will come along and be able to help you out better than I could. I've also added a little something to the question that only you'll know what it is ;-) cheers and good luck.